# Eigenvalues of $BB^T$ where $B$ is the Incidence Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

> Let $I_n, J_n \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $I_n$ is the identity and $(J_n)_{ij} = 1$ for all $i,j$.
>
> (1) Calculate the determinant, eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $I_n$ and $J_n$.
>
> (2) Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A_{a,b} = aI_n + bJ_n$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $A_{a,b}$ is symmetric.
>
> (3) Calculate the determinant of $A_{a,b}$.
>
> If $X = \{x_1,...,x_m\}$ and $A = \{A_1,...,A_n\}$ is a family of subsets of $X$, the Incidence Matrix $B$ of $A$ is defined by $B_{ij} = 1$ if $x_j \in A_i$ and $B_{ij} = 0$ if $x_j \not\in A_i$. What is the meaning of $BB^T$? Calculate the eigenvalues of $BB^T$.

(1) *For $I_n$*:

- $\det I_n = 1$;
- The only eigenvalue is $1$, since $I_nh = h$ for all $h$;
- The eigenvectors are $e_1,...,e_n$, since for each $h$, $h = a_1e_1 + \cdots + a_ne_n$.

*For $J_n$*:

- $\det J_n = 0$;
- We have that $\det(J_n - \lambda I_n) = \pm\lambda^{n} \mp n\lambda^{n-1} = \pm\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda - n)$, so the eigenvalues are $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $n$ with multiplicity $1$.

If $\lambda = 0$, then

$$(J_n - 0I_n)h = (0,...,0)^T \Longrightarrow (h_1 + \cdots + h_n,0,...,0)^T = (0,0,...,0)^T.$$

So, $h = (h_1,...,h_n)^T = (-h_2 - \cdots -h_n, h_2,...,h_n)^T$. Thus, the eigenvalues are $\{(-1,1,0,...,0)^T, (-1,0,1,0,...,0)^T,...,(-1,0,...,1,0)^T,(-1,0,...,0,1)^T\}$.

If $\lambda = n$, then

$$(J_n - nI_n)h = (0,...,0)^T \Longrightarrow h_1 = \cdots = h_n$$

from where the eigenvector is $(1,...,1)^T$.

(2) By definition $(A_{a,b})_{ij} = a + b$ if $i=j$ and $(A_{a,b})_{ij} = b$ if $i \neq j$. We have that

$$\det(A_{a,b} - \lambda I_n) = \pm(\lambda - a)^{n-1}(\lambda - a - nb).$$

Then, the eigenvalues are $a$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $a+nb$ with multiplicity $1$.

*For $\lambda = a$:*

$$(A_{a,b} - aI_n)h = 0 \Longrightarrow h_1 = -h_2 - \cdots - h_n.$$

Thus the eigenvectors are $\{(-1,1,0,...,0)^T, (-1,0,1,0,...,0)^T,...,(-1,0,...,1,0)^T,(-1,0,...,0,1)^T\}$

*For $\lambda = a + nb:$*

$$(A_{a,b}-(a+nb)I_n)h = 0 \Longrightarrow h_1 = \cdots = h_n.$$

Thus the eigenvalue is $(1,...,1)^T$.

(3) $\det A_{a,b} = a^{n-1}(a + nb)$.

---

**Question 1.** I cannot prove that
$$\det(J_n - \lambda I_n) = \pm \lambda^{n-1}(\lambda - n)$$
$$\det(A_{a,b} - \lambda I_n) = \pm(\lambda - a)^{n-1}(\lambda - a - nb)$$
for the general case. I only check for some small $n$. My first attempt was induction and cofactor expansion, but I cannot conclude.

**Question 2.** Taking $\lambda = 0$ we get $\det(A_{a,b}) = \pm(-a)^{n-1}(-a-nb)$, but some calculations show that $\det(A_{a,b}) = a^{n-1}(a + nb)$. Why this difference? Is there some mistake?

**Question 3.**  I don't know the meaning of $BB^T$. Moreover, since $B$ depends on the connections between $x_j$ and $A_i$, I cannot see a viable way to calculate the eigenvalues. I think that there is a connection with the previuous itens, but I cannot see.

I apologize for the long question.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** Consider the matrix $J_n$. It has rank 1, thus $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity at least $n-1$.

Since the $n=tr(J_n)=\lambda_1+...+\lambda_n$ it follows that the last eigenvalue of $J_n$ is $n$.

Then 
$$\det(xI_n-J_n)=(x-\lambda_1)...(x-\Lambda_n)=x^{n-1}(n-n)$$

**Alternate solution**
$$\det(J_n - \lambda I_n)= \det \begin{bmatrix} 
1-\lambda & 1 & 1 &1 ...&1 \\
1& 1-\lambda  & 1 &1 ...&1 \\
...&...&...&...&...&\\
1& 1  & 1 &1 ...&1-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Add all rows to the first
$$\det(J_n - \lambda I_n)= \det \begin{bmatrix} 
n-\lambda & n-\lambda & n-\lambda &n-\lambda ...&n-\lambda \\
1& 1-\lambda  & 1 &1 ...&1 \\
...&...&...&...&...&\\
1& 1  & 1 &1 ...&1-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}\\= (n-\lambda)
\det \begin{bmatrix} 
1 &1 & 1 &1 ...&1\\
1& 1-\lambda  & 1 &1 ...&1 \\
...&...&...&...&...&\\
1& 1  & 1 &1 ...&1-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, subtract the first row from the rest:
$$\det(J_n - \lambda I_n)=(n-\lambda)
\det \begin{bmatrix} 
1 &1 & 1 &1 ...&1\\
0& -\lambda  & 0 &0 ...&0 \\
...&...&...&...&...&\\
0& 0  & 0 &0 ...&-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}=(n-\lambda)(-\lambda)^{n-1}
$$

Then 
$$\det(A_{a,b} - \lambda I_n) = \det(b \left(J_n -\frac{(\lambda-a)}{b} I_n\right)=b^n (n-\frac{(\lambda-a)}{b})(-\frac{(\lambda-a)}{b})^{n-1}$$ by the above with $\lambda$ replaced by $\frac{(\lambda-a)}{b}$.

**Question 2:**
$$(-a)^{n-1}(-a-nb)=(-1)^{n-1} a^{n-1} (-1)(a+nb)= (-1)^n a^{n-1}(a+nb)$$
which is consistent with what you get in (a) is you write properly the choice of $\pm$.

**Question 3** $B^T$ means the transpose matrix. $BB^T$ mean $B$ multiplied with its transpose. The problem is expecting you to realize what this means in terms of vertices/edges of the graph, if you figure this you'll likely know how to solve the last part.